# Moving aws-exports.js to another Angular Project?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

If we want to use the same pool in two different Angular applications can we simply copy `aws-exports` to the other application and configure the Auth category in `main.ts` or do we have to run `amplify init` on the project.  I know that we need to do the scaffolding steps documented here:

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/getting-angular-ready-for-aws-amplify-fc33f07f14a2

I've tried it and it does not work, so it seems like perhaps we have to run `amplify init` but I wanted to double check if anyone has tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a change to the configuration process.  Auth has to be configured like this now:

```
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core'
import { Auth } from '@aws-amplify/auth'
import awsconfig from './aws-exports'

Amplify.configure(awsconfig)
Auth.configure(awsconfig)
```

Whereas before just doing:

```
Amplify.configure(awsconfig)
```

Was enough.

Comment: May I ask the difference between `import Amplify , { Auth }  from 'aws-amplify';` and what you listed.  I feel like the last few months I've drifted a little and I don't know if I should be using @aws-amplify vs aws-amplify?

Comment: In my last Angular 10 project which is https://fireflysemantics.com/ I'm using `import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';`

Comment: Thanks I double checked package sizes after build, and didn't see any major diff.  I got worried as my 'import cost' plugin in VSCode was telling me it was adding some heft with the @aws-amplify references.